# File.Move atomic operation

Tags: c#, file, atomic

I am trying to generate a huge text file using C# and another process is constantly looking at the location and trying to pickup the file if available.

In order to make the file atomic below are the steps :

```
1 - Write to file : Filename_temp.txt
2 - Check if Filename.txt already exists then Delete
3 - Do a File.Move to the same destination     
    From filename : Filename_temp.txt 
    TO : Filename.txt
```

Since C# does not have a rename, I have to rely on File.Move, does this make sure the move operation will be atomic or is there another way to achieve this atomicity?

Comment: what do you *exactly* mean, by saying: atomic move ?

Comment: Can you update both applications logic? If yes - use Mutex to sync access

Comment: I recommend checking for existence and deleting first. You never know, when `Filename_temp.txt` might already exist.

Comment: This is a Windows limitation rather than a c# one

Comment: @Tigran, he wants the file to be complete before it is visible to the other process.

Comment: @Tigran Atomic in this context means "all or nothing" so basically the file is not available to the watcher until its completely written.

Comment: @sll the other application is out of my control and I have no rights to change that application.

Comment: This is essentially the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222119/atomic-file-copy-under-net

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the MSDN blog article [How to do atomic writes in a file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/12/28/507866.aspx), renaming an NTFS file is an atomic operation:

> The solution? Let's remember that metadata changes are atomic. Rename is such a case. So, we can just perform the write to a temporary file, and after we know that the writes are on the disk (completed and flushed) then we can interchange the old file with the new file.

Granted, this does not guarantee that `File.Move` just issues an NTFS rename operation, but I can't think of a valid reason why it should do anything more complicated.

Comment: Sure there's a reason: the file could be moved to a different device.

Answer (score 4):

File.Move should be a 'rename' if the source and destination are on the same volume. So, regardless of file size, the Move should be 'instant'. I presume that is your concern?

From a FAQ from a MS employee on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx we have;

'Frequently asked question: Is MoveFileEx atomic if the existing and new files are both on the same drive?

The simple answer is "usually, but in some cases it will silently fall-back to a non-atomic method, so don't count on it".'

I guess if it's 100% critical you could look at Transactional NTFS. I'm not sure if there are wrappers in .Net for this yet, so you may need to use P/Invoke.

Comment: Exactly, is that documented somewhere ?

Comment: Can't find anything at the moment, it's more a feature of NTFS rather than .Net though. Will try to find references.

Comment: +1. There seem to be contradicting sources *from Microsoft* on this point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of windows, rather than c# or the .Net Framework.

See here

[Atomicity of File.Move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774098/atomicity-of-file-move)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your file directly to the destination and use a zero-size signal file that is created after you huge file is ready. Your reader process can look for a signal file and read a huge file after the signal file is available. I think that can solve the "atomicity" problem.

Comment: Basically the semaphore files indicating DONE, however this requires the watching process to change which is unfortunately out of my bounds.