# How do I create an already populated text file?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, filestream

I want to create a text file with the extension .jrq and populate it with two lines. However I want this to happen "all at once" instead of creating the text file and *then* adding the two lines. Basically I need to create an already populated text file.

Here is my current code:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(folder + filename + ".jrq", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

streamWriter.WriteLine("Line1");
streamWriter.WriteLine("Line2");

streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
```

The reason I need the file creation and the file appending to happen together is because I have a windows service that scans the folder that this text file will be created in and that service triggers a job the second it sees a .jrq file (and does logic based on what's written in the file). It notices the .jrq file before I've written anything in it and throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are better off using a small trick. As adv12 pointed out writing all at once with one single method does not guarantee the implementation is atomic. if I were you I would create a temporary file:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(folder + filename + ".tmp", 

FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

streamWriter.WriteLine("Line1");
streamWriter.WriteLine("Line2");

streamWriter.Flush();
streamWriter.Close();
```

and then rename it using [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx):

```
System.IO.File.Move(folder + filename + ".tmp",folder + filename + ".jrq");
```

So the job will start when the file jrq is full of data. it's not a super elegant solution but it would work.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could write the file with a different filename, then move it once you've populated it.  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774098/atomicity-of-file-move), file moves are atomic within NTFS, so your service would never see a half-written file.

Answer (score 0):

File.WriteAllText is what you're looking for. If the file does not exist, it will create it with the text in it on creation.

Comment: The fact that it's provided as a single method in the framework doesn't guarantee that the implementation is atomic...